# Knockout $parent doubts when using "with" to set context

Tags: knockout.js

I have 3 level nested model like this

```
WebsiteViewModel => MenuViewModel => MenuEntryViewModel
```

`WebsiteViewModel` is the root model. Now in the html Template meant for `MenuEntryViewModel` I set the binding context to **MenuEntryViewModel** using **["with"](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)** as given below

```
<div id="contextSetter" data-bind="with: menuViewModel.menuEntryViewModel">
    <div data-bind="event: {'hidden.bs.modal': function() {console.log($parent);}}">
    ...
    </div>
</div
```

The above event binding surprisingly logs **WebsiteViewModel** object instead of **MenuViewModel**

So, if currently the binding context is **menuViewModel.menuEntryViewModel** then the $parent does not point to **menuViewModel**, it points **WebsiteViewModel** (the root model in this case). Although I can use a work-around for this, I think $parent should be pointing to the **MenuViewModel**. Any comments about this behavior?

Comment: I think it's by design, because you are chaining `with: menuViewModel.menuEntryViewModel` together, the parent context of those 2 items together is `WebsiteViewModel`.

Comment: @Tanner's correct I think (you should post it as an answer), as demonstrated by [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L295t7f8/) vs [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fL4jd9yu/)

Comment: @Jeroen are you referring to me or OP with regards to posting answer?

Comment: @Tanner you should, your comment *is* the answer as far as I can tell. You deserve internetpoints for this! Feel free to use code from / links to the fiddles if you found them useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design because you are chaining `with: menuViewModel.menuEntryViewModel` together, the parent context of those 2 items together is `WebsiteViewModel`.

Check these samples posted by @Jeroen:

### [Your Nested Structure](http://jsfiddle.net/L295t7f8/)

In this example, the chaining of `menuViewModel.menuEntryViewModel`, shows the context is considered as a single context, where `$parent` is `WebsiteViewModel`.

**Markup**

```
<div id="contextSetter" data-bind="with: menuViewModel.menuEntryViewModel">
    <div data-bind="click: function() {console.log($parent);}">
        click me to see console.log
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var websiteViewModel  = {
    txt: 'website',
    menuViewModel: {
        txt: 'menu',
        menuEntryViewModel: {
            txt: 'entry'
        }
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(websiteViewModel);
```

In this example, you could modify it to `console.log($parent.menuViewModel)`, which would navigate to the view model you are expecting if you need to access it's properties.

### [Modified Structure](http://jsfiddle.net/fL4jd9yu/)

In this example, without the chaining, the context is the individual item and `$parent` is evaluated as expected.

**Markup**

```
<div id="contextSetter" data-bind="with: menuViewModel">
    <div data-bind="click: function() {console.log($parent);}">
        top-click-me to see console.log
    </div>
    <div id="subContextSetter" data-bind="with: menuEntryViewModel">
        <div data-bind="click: function() {console.log($parent);}">
            click me to see console.log
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var websiteViewModel  = {
    txt: 'website',
    menuViewModel: {
        txt: 'menu',
        menuEntryViewModel: {
            txt: 'entry'
        }
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(websiteViewModel);
```

Comment: much better than mine!"

Comment: @ChrisMeek, Tanner, That looks good. Also there is another way of switching contexts without introducing any html element specifically, as explained at the end of page here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html. I think these ways are more than sufficient to get the desired result. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Basically read the `$parent` variable slightly differently.  Basically `with` establishes a new context inside the context set to `WebsiteViewModel`,  the `MenuViewModel` is never actually set to a context, hence why it is missing.  You could do the following...

```
<div data-bind="with: menuViewModel">
  <div id="contextSetter" data-bind="with: menuEntryViewModel">
    <div data-bind="event: {'hidden.bs.modal': function() {console.log($parent);}}">
    ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would force the `menuViewModel` to show up as `$parent` as you are expecting.